# How to ensure that at least one of two methods in Java class is overridden?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a base Java class, which has two similar methods:

```java
class Base {
    public void processA(SomeClass sc, Args args);
    public void processB(AnotherClass ac, Args argc);
}
```

I would like to create a descendant, which must implement at least one of these two methods of the Base class. For instance, I consider following variants are correct (**"good"**):

```java
class ChildA extends Base {
    public void processA(SomeClass sc, Args args);
}

class ChildB extends Base {
    public void processB(AnotherClass ac, Args args);
}
```

But the following variant is wrong (let's call it **"bad"**):

```java
class ChildC extends Base {
    /* nothing here */
}
```

So the question is how methods `process{A,B}` must be implemented/designated to allow detection of such "bad" and "good" implementation of the childs at compile time?

Now I'm using run-time detection like this:

```java
class Base {
    public void processA(SomeClass sc, Args args) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Hey, buddy, you forget to implement this, but calling it.");
    }
    public void processB(AnotherClass ac, Args argc) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Hey, buddy, you forget to implement this, but calling it.");
    }
}
```

Maybe there is another good approach to do this?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/181277); why do you need to do this?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm refactoring an old code and faced this. Your question gave me idea, that such an odd code can be result of poor architecture of classes. Perhaps base can be split in two different classes. If I fail with this idea, I will write another one question with architecture description of my problem. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this **cause it defeats polymorphism**. Since you don't provide an implementation for your methods ,your `Base` should be either `abstract` or an `interface`.

*In your example both methods must be overriden.*

My approach is to change your design. Since the only thing I can see similar to your methods is the signature.

[image: uml design]

First make a concrete class implementing the *process* method, therefore having your `Base` class loose coupled you can pass different classes.

You can also extend you paradigm using [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) design pattern if you want to have multiple processes.

*A simpler approach is to make an empty implementation.*

Answer (score -1):

Declare your methods `abstract`. Any class that extends a class with abstract methods must implement them.

Comment: He said *at least one* meaning one can be left.

Comment: Then make an empty implementation for one. By his example, it seems that he does not want others to forget they need to implement, not that *only one must* be implemented.